# Are unnamed namespaces legal?

Tags: c++, namespaces, unnamed-namespace

> ```cpp
> namespace { int Foo (int a); }
> ```

Is this code snippet legal? If so, can I reference Foo in anywhere, or only in a certain domain?

Comment: It is legal, but means something different than a regular namespace. :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is legal, You can use `Foo` anywhere in the same **[Translation Unit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1106149/what-is-a-translation-unit-in-c)**.

Anonymous namespace is the standard prescribed way of saying `static` on variables to limit their scope to the same Translation unit.

**C++03 Standard section 7.3.1.1 Unnamed namespaces**

para 2:

> The use of the static keyword is deprecated when declaring objects in a namespace scope, the unnamed-namespace provides a superior alternative.

---

**Update:**
As @Matthieu M. correctly points out in the comments, and **[his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7670978/c-namespace-anonymous-namespace-is-legal/7671418#7671418)** The C++11 Standard removed the above quote from C++03 Standard, which implies that the `static` keyword is not deprecated when declaring objects in a namespace scope, Anonymous or Unnamed namespaces are still valid nevertheless.

Comment: My answer is slightly different, but a little bit more correct I think ;)

Comment: @BjörnPollex: Ah it was my second edit made our answers same lol

Comment: And now we both added standard quotes :)

Comment: @BjörnPollex: And then I added link to `What is an Translation Unit` :-)

Comment: @BjörnPollex: Well, let me upvote you too, for your answer came in as quick as was mine & is as accurate as well. C++ Wins :)

Comment: @Als: your answer is, however, *deprecated*. In C++11, the commitee backed out and the use of the `static` keyword is no longer described as deprecated :)

Comment: @MatthieuM.: I don't have the C++11 standard handy right now, but I will look it up and modify accordingly, thanks for the heads up! :)

Comment: @Als: I've reproduced it below (same paragraph) in its entirety. The mention about deprecation has been removed. I think the rationale was that it would be yet another hurdle for compatibility with C.

Comment: @MatthieuM.: Yes, you are correct, I had edited the answer to reflect it, the same time while you posted the answer, Now I have edited to link to your answer. Thanks.

Comment: @MatthieuM.: So this means we should still prefer unnamed namespaces to `static`, even though it is no longer deprecated?

Comment: @BjörnPollex: I think it means that we are free to do however we please. I must admit that I tend to use `static` when I only have a function or constant to declare, I find it clearer because `static` is right next to the definition so it's clear whether in an unnamed namespace it's not immediately clear. However I do use unnamed namespaces whenever I have class definitions, and in this case I pack all the stuff in there.... call me fickle :D

Answer (score 5):

This is legal. You can reference `Foo` anywhere inside the translation-unit.

From the C++03-standard, Section 7.3.1.1:

> An unnamed-namespace-definition behaves as if it were replaced by
>
> ```
> namespace unique { /* empty body */ } using namespace unique;
> namespace unique { namespace-body }
> ```
>
> where all occurrences of `unique` in
>   a translation unit are replaced by the same identifier and this
>   identifier differs from all other identifiers in the entire program.
>
> The use of the static keyword is deprecated when declaring objects in
>   a namespace scope; the unnamed-namespace provides a superior
>   alternative.

Comment: `unnamed-namespace-definition behaves as if it were replaced by ...`. I beg to differ here. In case of unnamed `namespace` you can declare/define a variable inside it. However, in case of normal `namespace` you cannot (because it will cause multiple symbol linker error). So both doesn't have the same effect.

Comment: @iammilind: Since `unique` (which is the name of that namespace) is different for all translation-units, you will never have multiply defined symbols. Also, this is a quote from the standard, so if you beg to differ, take it up with the committee ;)

Comment: Ok, I thought `unique` is just a name. I din't know standard committee would put such confusing example :)). May be `namespace <unique name> { ... } using namespace <unique name>;` would have been appropriate wording.

Comment: @iammilind: the standard uses a different typeface to indicate that *unique* isn't literally part of the code; I guess they also assumed that people would read to the end of the sentence.

Comment: @MikeSeymour, yup agreed. My mistake. And +1 to this answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

The definition changed slightly in the C++11 Standard:

> **7.3.1.1 Unnamed namespaces [namespace.unnamed]**
>
> **1/** An unnamed-namespace-definition behaves as if it were replaced by

```
inlineoptnamespace unique { /* empty body */ }
using namespace unique ;
namespace unique { namespace-body }
```

> where inline appears if and only if it appears in the unnamed-namespace-definition, all occurrences of unique in a translation unit are replaced by the same identifier, and this identifier differs from all other identifiers in the entire program.94 *[ Example:*

```
namespace { int i; } // unique ::i
void f() { i++; } // unique ::i++

namespace A {
  namespace {
    int i; // A:: unique ::i
    int j; // A:: unique ::j
  }
  void g() { i++; } // A:: unique ::i++
}

using namespace A;

void h() {
  i++; // error: unique ::i or A:: unique ::i
  A::i++; // A:: unique ::i
  j++; // A:: unique ::j
}
```

> *—end example ]*